# Save form data so that it doesn't get lost when page gets refreshed in php

Tags: javascript, php, cookies

I have a registration form, but when the page refreshes the data is lost and the user has to enter the data again. I want the data to remain there even if the page refreshes.

I am using the `serialize` function to serialize the form data but now how should I print the stored values when page is refreshed?

```
setcookie('formdata', serialize($formdata), time()+30*24*60*60);
```

But it is saving the data at the end. I want the data to be stored as soon as the user enters the value and if the page refreshes and the field was filled it should populate the data.

Comment: you can use session for it....

Comment: If the page just refreshed or if your form is submitted, in case it has errors the form data wouldn't be lost? Is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: I dont want to store the data on server I want to store on the client side only

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Save data on form submit or save data everytime a user enters something in the input field?

Comment: You say `registration form` and you say `but when the page refreshes the data is lost`? What do you mean refreshed? When the form in submitted - then it's lost as it has errors in it and a user has to again stay with registration form?

Comment: @ Ilia Rostovtsev : I want to save data everytime a user enters something in the input field, so that if the page get refreshed/connection is lost.and he open the form the data which he filled previously should be there until the user submits the form.

Comment: Yes, you can do it using cookies on client-side!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of saving the cookies with PHP, you do need to do it with Javascript / JQuery.
You can do it everytime the user types on an input box ([.change](http://api.jquery.com/change/)).

Have a look at: [How do I set/unset cookie with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458724/how-to-set-unset-cookie-with-jquery)

Comment: but if i put setCookie(key, value) again each field in form and check if its set then print the value while the form loads will it not work fine for me

Comment: use `$.cookie(cookie,value)` to save the cookie with Javascript. Then, when loading the form page, print the value of the cookie inside the input boxes with PHP. `$_['COOKIE']`

Answer (score 0):

you can use javascript to save form values into cookies. use jquery $.cookie function on change event. also you can use javascript without jquery

```
function setCookie(name, value, days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        var expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
    }
    else
        var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
}

function getCookie(c_name) {
    if (document.cookie.length > 0) {
        c_start = document.cookie.indexOf(c_name + "=");
        if (c_start != -1) {
            c_start = c_start + c_name.length + 1;
            c_end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", c_start);
            if (c_end == -1) {
                c_end = document.cookie.length;
            }
            return unescape(document.cookie.substring(c_start, c_end));
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

just use these functions to store and load cookie by name.